# add 1 to field name with perimeters at end Advanced custom fields WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops

I am using Advanced Custom Fields in WordPress and trying to poop and increment a integer on the end of a field name, this works well until I add a perimeters then it dose not work.

for example

**works**

```
 <h3 style="min-height: 150px">test<?php the_field_1('text_', false, false) ?></h3>
```

**works**

```
 <h3 style="min-height: 150px">test<?php the_field('text_' . ($i+1))?></h3>
```

dos not work (but need working)

```
<h3 style="min-height: 150px">test<?php the_field('text_' . ($i+1)), false, false) ?></h3>
```

Dose anyone know how to get around this or if there is a proper way of doing this with perimeters ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<h3 style="min-height: 150px">test<?php the_field('text_' . ($i+1)), false, false) ?></h3>
// to many brackets the error is here, remove this one            ^
```

In fact to simplify you could use

```
<h3 style="min-height: 150px">test<?php the_field('text_' . $i+1, false, false) ?></h3>
```

as the brackets are achieving little or nothing anyway